# Custom Display Modes on a custom entity type

Tags: 8

I have created a custom entity type (without bundles) using the Drupal Console command. 
Everything works fine with the out the box stuff. I can configure fields, the order of the form and the order of the output display.

However, it seems impossible to add and new View Modes to my new entity type. I have tried adding a new mode to the "Content" view modes section but I don't have the collapsable details section to be able to enable new view modes.

Is there a setting I have missed in the entity code that will display this?

Comment: It is possible to add new view modes in UI. When you go to */admin/structure/display-modes/view/add* you should be able the select the custom entity (and not "Content", which would be the wrong entity).

Comment: Newly created custom content entities do NOT show up in the UI at `/admin/structure/display-modes/view/add`, unless you also explicitly create at least one view mode programmatically for that entity (see @Jimmyb_1991's answer below). After at least one view mode exists, additional view modes can be added using the UI.

Comment: At least in newer Drupal versions (D10) you can now create view modes via the UI (for older versions I don't know if this works).

To do this, go to the page mentioned and click on "Add view mode" at the top.
The new custom entity should now also be selectable there.

Answer (score 10):

This can also be achieved through the UI.

1. Logged in as admin, press Structure > Display modes > View modes > Add ( /admin/structure/display-modes/view/add )
2. Select your custom entity type to add a display mode
3. Enter a name for the display mode

Comment: This does not work for the very first view mode of your custom content entity. The first one must be created using code/config, only after that additional views modes can be added through the UI

Comment: Works for me. Nice and simple..

Answer (score 7):

As always, I found the answer just after posting the question.

For others looking for the same thing, you need to create an install .yml file in your custom module.
I found this by looking at the Media module in core.

In your module create config/install/core.entity_view_mode.ENTITY_TYPE_ID.NAME_OF_VIEW_MODE_TO_CREATE.yml that implements the following:

```
langcode: en # Or your default site language
status: false
dependencies:
  module:
    - my_module
id: entity_type_id.name_of_view_mode_to_create
label: 'My new View Mode'
targetEntityType: entity_type_id
cache: true
```

I hope this helps someone else too :D

Comment: I tried this and it did not work for me. Maybe because I need to reinstall the module? This is something I am averse to doing as I do not want to lose all content etc. (although might not be too bad) Solution for me was to navigate to `/admin/structure/display-modes/view` as already mentioned by Ashraf Abed