# How do I add a view mode to a simple custom entity?

Tags: 8, entities

I have created a super-simple drupal 8 custom entity.  We now need a custom view mode for this entity.  What do I need to add to my definition to make my entity appear as an option on the 'Add View Mode' page: /admin/structure/display-modes/view/add ?

My super-simple entity definition is

```
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "schedulecal",
 *   label = @Translation("ScheduleCalendar"),
 *   base_table = "scheduler_entity_calendars",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *   },
 * )
```

I can't find this info anywhere in doc.

Comment: Related: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/271283/custom-display-modes-on-a-custom-entity-type

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a view builder class in the handler section:

```
 *   handlers = {
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
```

and a field UI route:

```
 *   field_ui_base_route = "my_entity.settings",
```

pointing at the config form for the settings of your entity type. If you don't have settings return at least a #markup element:

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['my_entity_settings']['#markup'] = 'Settings form for My Entity entities. Manage field settings here.';
    return $form;
  }
```

Comment: I also had to add a route to my_entity.settings passing it the form like so - form: '\Drupal\my_module\Form\MySettingsForm'

Comment: Oh and to actually theme the view mode via a template you will need to implement a theme hook, as outlined here https://jimconte.com/blog/web/themeing-a-custom-content-entity