# How do I add fields to an existing custom entity?

Tags: entities, 9

I have a custom entity that fieldable. I need to add a field to it, and I want to do it through the UI. The entity was created in a custom module, which I can modify.

How can I make the entity fieldable?

```
/**
 * Defines the Quiz entity.
 *
 * @ingroup qwizard
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "qwiz",
 *   label = @Translation("Quiz"),
 *   bundle_label = @Translation("Quiz type"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "storage" = "Drupal\qwizard\QwizStorage",
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\qwizard\QwizListBuilder",
 *     "views_data" = "Drupal\qwizard\Entity\QwizViewsData",
 *
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\qwizard\Form\QwizForm",
 *       "add" = "Drupal\qwizard\Form\QwizForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\qwizard\Form\QwizForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\qwizard\Form\QwizDeleteForm",
 *     },
 *     "access" = "Drupal\qwizard\QwizAccessControlHandler",
 *     "route_provider" = {
 *       "html" = "Drupal\qwizard\QwizHtmlRouteProvider",
 *     },
 *   },
 *   base_table = "qwiz",
 *   revision_table = "qwiz_revision",
 *   revision_data_table = "qwiz_field_revision",
 *   admin_permission = "administer quiz entities",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "revision" = "vid",
 *     "bundle" = "type",
 *     "label" = "name",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *     "uid" = "user_id",
 *     "langcode" = "langcode",
 *     "status" = "status",
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz/{qwiz}",
 *     "add-page" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz/add",
 *     "add-form" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz/add/{qwiz_type}",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz/{qwiz}/edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz/{qwiz}/delete",
 *     "version-history" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz/{qwiz}/revisions",
 *     "revision" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz/{qwiz}/revisions/{qwiz_revision}/view",
 *     "revision_revert" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz/{qwiz}/revisions/{qwiz_revision}/revert",
 *     "revision_delete" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz/{qwiz}/revisions/{qwiz_revision}/delete",
 *     "collection" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz",
 *   },
 *   bundle_entity_type = "qwiz_type",
 *   field_ui_base_route = "entity.qwiz_type.edit_form"
 * )
 */
```

Comment: Do you have `bundle_entity_type` set in your entity annotation?

Comment: Actually if you could edit the question and copy/paste the whole annotation that would be helpful

Comment: If the answer to the question of @Clive is no and you want to make a simple entity field-able: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/283826/how-do-i-add-a-view-mode-to-a-simple-custom-entity

Comment: The annotation is missing the value for *data_table*. The annotation isn't sufficient to make an entity fieldable; the entity class must also implement a specific interface. What's the exact issue you are having, though? The question just says what you want to achieve, not the problem you need to resolve. Is *entity.qwiz_type.edit_form* the correct route for the bundle edit form?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a `field_ui_base_route` to the entity annotation. The value should be the route ID for the edit form of the config entity type used to provide the bundles.

So if your entity ID is `foo` and the bundle config entity ID is `foo_type`, that would be:

```
@ContentEntityType(
  id = "foo",
  ...
  field_ui_base_route = "entity.foo_type.edit_form"
)
```

Rebuild the cache, and you should see the relevant menu links and tabs when you manage your bundles in the UI.

Comment: Hi Clive, I added the annotation to the original post.  It does have the field_ui_base_route set. Thanks.